# Rotate a buffered image in Java

Tags: java, rotation, bufferedimage, graphics2d, image-rotation

I am trying to rotate a buffered image in java. Here is the code I am using:

```java
public static BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage bimg, double angle) {
    int w = bimg.getWidth();
    int h = bimg.getHeight();
    Graphics2D graphic = bimg.createGraphics();
    graphic.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), w / 2, h / 2);
    graphic.drawImage(bimg, null, 0, 0);
    graphic.dispose();
    return bimg;
}
```

I have looked a numerous stack overflow questions and answers on this topic and not been able to figure out why the image is chopped up the way it is when I try to rotate it. Here is an example showing a loaded image:
[loaded image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnZfy.png)

After I click the rotate button which calls the above function with the buffered image and a 90.0 for the angle:
[chopped up image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Euz7.png)

Can someone help me understand what is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 38):

As always, the Internet to the rescue. So, this is some code which I hobbled together from other resources/post/blogs which will return a new image which is sized so it will contain the rotated image

```
public BufferedImage rotateImageByDegrees(BufferedImage img, double angle) {
    double rads = Math.toRadians(angle);
    double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(rads)), cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(rads));
    int w = img.getWidth();
    int h = img.getHeight();
    int newWidth = (int) Math.floor(w * cos + h * sin);
    int newHeight = (int) Math.floor(h * cos + w * sin);

    BufferedImage rotated = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = rotated.createGraphics();
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.translate((newWidth - w) / 2, (newHeight - h) / 2);

    int x = w / 2;
    int y = h / 2;

    at.rotate(rads, x, y);
    g2d.setTransform(at);
    g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2d.drawRect(0, 0, newWidth - 1, newHeight - 1);
    g2d.dispose();

    return rotated;
}
```

**Updated**

So, using this PNG:

[image]

And this code...

```
package javaapplication1.pkg040;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage master;
        private BufferedImage rotated;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                master = ImageIO.read(new File("/Volumes/Disk02/Dropbox/MegaTokyo/Miho_Small.png"));
                rotated = rotateImageByDegrees(master, 0.0);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                private double angle = 0;
                private double delta = 1.0;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    angle += delta;
                    rotated = rotateImageByDegrees(master, angle);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return master == null
                         ? new Dimension(200, 200)
                         : new Dimension(master.getWidth(), master.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (rotated != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = (getWidth() - rotated.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - rotated.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(rotated, x, y, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

        public BufferedImage rotateImageByDegrees(BufferedImage img, double angle) {

            double rads = Math.toRadians(angle);
            double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(rads)), cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(rads));
            int w = img.getWidth();
            int h = img.getHeight();
            int newWidth = (int) Math.floor(w * cos + h * sin);
            int newHeight = (int) Math.floor(h * cos + w * sin);

            BufferedImage rotated = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = rotated.createGraphics();
            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.translate((newWidth - w) / 2, (newHeight - h) / 2);

            int x = w / 2;
            int y = h / 2;

            at.rotate(rads, x, y);
            g2d.setTransform(at);
            g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
            g2d.dispose();

            return rotated;
        }
    }

}
```

I can generate something like...

[image: Rotating]

Comment: Oddly enough the images that I am working with will not rotate and lock up my program. The images are created by converting values in a binary file to grayscale and then stored in a bufferedimage. I tried one that I saved to PNG and it failed to rotate as well. The only images that will rotate are ones loaded from a JPEG format. Any thoughts?

Comment: So, I've re-tested the code using a PNG based image and it works fine for me.  I suggest you consider asking a new question and provide a runnable example which demonstrates your problem as it would seem to more related to "how" you're using the code, from my perspective

Comment: @MadProgrammer Fair points all around. I'd rather know why as well but my thought was if you knew who, you could find out why. Ah, but....  c`est la vie.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I have a question regarding your code: In the rotateImagesByDegree(...) , almost at the bottom there is the line: g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this); This quite confueses me, as it seems as if the original image (un-rotated) is painted. Then above in the paintComponent, there is : g2d.drawImage(rotated, x, y, this); The code works fine, but could you please elaborate why you have two paint-statements? Thanks.

Comment: @GitPhilter Did you see the line `g2d.setTransform(at);`?  This is applying a transformation to the `Graphics` context, which defines the rotation logic

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, I see it. I don´t know if we are talking about the same thing, though. I wanted to understand why there are TWO different paint-statements in two different spots. Why can we not just always paint the rotated image in the paintComponent()? Whats the logic behind this?

Comment: @GitPhilter Ok, so `rotateImageByDegrees` is taking the original image and rotating it by a set number of degrees.  This generates a new `BufferedImage`.  `paintComponent` is simply painting the rotated image to the screen, so you can see the result.  So, you could take `rotateImageByDegrees` and rotate an image and, I don't know, save it or do what ever you want - or, if you wanted to, as the example does, animate it

Comment: Nice solution, I was trying to convert resultant rotated `BufferedImage` to `byte[]`. I always get zero length byte array. Finally, I found solution; is to replace  `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` with `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` . Do you have solution to get conversion work while keeping `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`?

Comment: @SalehRezq There shouldn’t be any difference

Answer (score 12):

This code reads an image from a file, rotates it by a certain angle, and writes to another file. It works fine with `png` images with transparency:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(
            Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/image.png"));

    BufferedImage rotated = rotateImage(image, 45);

    ImageIO.write(rotated, "png",
            new FileOutputStream("resources/rotated.png"));
}
```

```java
private static BufferedImage rotateImage(BufferedImage buffImage, double angle) {
    double radian = Math.toRadians(angle);
    double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(radian));
    double cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(radian));

    int width = buffImage.getWidth();
    int height = buffImage.getHeight();

    int nWidth = (int) Math.floor((double) width * cos + (double) height * sin);
    int nHeight = (int) Math.floor((double) height * cos + (double) width * sin);

    BufferedImage rotatedImage = new BufferedImage(
            nWidth, nHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics2D graphics = rotatedImage.createGraphics();

    graphics.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);

    graphics.translate((nWidth - width) / 2, (nHeight - height) / 2);
    // rotation around the center point
    graphics.rotate(radian, (double) (width / 2), (double) (height / 2));
    graphics.drawImage(buffImage, 0, 0, null);
    graphics.dispose();

    return rotatedImage;
}
```

| image.png | rotated.png (45º) ⟳ | rotated.png (-45º) ⟲ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: image.png] | [image: rotated.png] | [image: rotated.png] |

Answer (score 11):

You get jumbled image result because you are drawing the rotated image into the input image itself. Instead you need to create graphic from a new BufferedImage.

```
public static BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage bimg, double angle) {

    int w = bimg.getWidth();    
    int h = bimg.getHeight();

    BufferedImage rotated = new BufferedImage(w, h, bimg.getType());  
    Graphics2D graphic = rotated.createGraphics();
    graphic.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), w/2, h/2);
    graphic.drawImage(bimg, null, 0, 0);
    graphic.dispose();
    return rotated;
}
```

Note that if you want to avoid getting cropped corners, you need to adjust width & height of the output BufferedImage.

Answer (score -3):

You'll have to account for resizing and new width and height for the output.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4787898/5420880

Comment: I am uncertain how the line GraphicsConfiguration gc = getDefaultConfiguration(); works. I googled it and see you need the GraphicsEnvironment and then GraphicsDevice. Not sure how to use it. I copied the function in the recommended link and it causes an error.