# Rotating a BufferedImage causes it to change its position

Tags: java, graphics, rotation, drawing, image-resizing

I'm trying to rotate a bunch of BufferedImage instances, the rotate works, but what's odd is that they change their position. Here's a snippet of how I do it.

```
BufferedImage philo1=ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\philo1.png"));
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();
    g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(15),philo1.getWidth()/2,philo1.getHeight()/2);
    g.drawImage(philo1,172, 48, 50, 50,this);
    g2d.setTransform(old);
}
```

the result is like this(with and without the rotation):

[image: Before the rotation]
[image: After the rotation]

What could be causing this? I suspect the reason is that I'm forcing the size of the image when I draw it, that's why it draws it in a different position, as I'm calling the rotation method before drawing. If this is the case, how can I solve this?

Comment: Looks to be because you are referencing the image by a corner. When you rotate it, the canvas size has now become larger. Instead of placing the image relative the corner, place it relative to the center.

Comment: You're not rotating the image, you rotating the entire `Graphics` context for the component

Comment: A better solution would be to rotate the image within it's own context, for [example, something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758061/rotate-a-buffered-image-in-java/37758533#37758533). This will generate a new image, rotated (and sized) based on your needs

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is, you're trying to rotate the entire `Graphics` context around the centre point of the image, if it were been drawn from the top/left corner of the context (0x0), but the image is offset.

Because rotating images with virtual space is so much fun, I prefer to generate a new image rotated within its own context and then simply paint that.  For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758061/rotate-a-buffered-image-in-java/37758533#37758533)

If that seems like to much work, then you will need to first translate the `Graphics` context in such away that the top/left corner is where the image is to be painted from, then you'll be able to rotate the image simple around it's centre/anchor point, for example:

[image: Various container sizes]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;
        private double rotationByDegrees = 45.0;

        public TestPane() throws IOException {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("/Users/shanewhitehead/Downloads/L05HK.png"));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return img == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (img != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.translate(x, y);
                g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotationByDegrees), img.getWidth() / 2, img.getHeight() / 2);
                g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Note: You could also use a `AffineTransform`, but I've just kept it simple