# How do I size the BufferedImage needed to hold all of a Graphics2D text rotated to an arbitrary angle?

Tags: java, rotation, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I create png Images from short pieces of text to be used as floating labels, prompts, speechbubbles, etc in a 3D graphics application. Occasionally some of my text needs to be rotated. Unfortunately the 3D application does not provide rotation for this kind of image. I have it fully working for both rotated and non-rotated text, and even the rotated images are drawn correctly if the text is short, but if I use a longer string, it gets cut off because the BufferedImage is not sized to handle it.  Do I need to use trigonometry to size it? I know I could always use a huge rectangle in the BufferedImage, but that seems inelegant.

Note that I only ever create single lines of text. If I need multiple lines occasionally, I use multiple images and stack them, it just works better for me that way.

Comment: *"Do I need to use trigonometry to size it?"* more or less yes - [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758061/rotate-a-buffered-image-in-java/37758533#37758533)

Comment: How do you rotate the text in the first place? If you use `AffineTransformOp` to rotate, it already has a [method to give you the bounds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html#getBounds2D(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)) required for the result...