# How would I go about rendering a transparent and rotated image in Java?

Tags: java, swing, transparency, image-rotation

I cannot seem to figure out how to draw a transparent and rotated image. I need to be able to draw an image that is transparent and rotated to a certain degree.

I tried this code:

```java
// draws an image that is rotated to a certain degree
public static void drawRotatedImage(BufferedImage image_, int x, int y, int degrees, float scale) {

    // graphics used for the utilities of drawing the image (processing)
    Graphics2D utilGraphics;

    // make rectangular image
    int radius = (int) Math.sqrt(image_.getWidth() * image_.getWidth() + image_.getHeight() * image_.getHeight());
    BufferedImage image1 = new BufferedImage(radius, radius, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    utilGraphics = image1.createGraphics();
// centers image
    utilGraphics.drawImage(image_, image1.getWidth() / 2 - image_.getWidth() / 2, image1.getHeight() / 2 - image_.getHeight() / 2, null);

    // scale image
    int nw = (int) (image1.getWidth() * scale);
    int nh = (int) (image1.getHeight() * scale);

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(nw, nh, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    utilGraphics.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, nw, nh, null);

    // Rotation information

    double rotationRequired = Math.toRadians (degrees);
    double locationX = image.getWidth() / 2;
    double locationY = image.getHeight() / 2;

    AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(rotationRequired, locationX, locationY);
    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

    ImageProducer filteredImgProd = new FilteredImageSource(op.filter(image, null).getSource(), filter);
    Image transparentImg = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(filteredImgProd);

    // Drawing the rotated image at the required drawing locations
    g2d.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(transparentImg.getSource()), x, y, null);
}
```

The filter variable is defined as:

```
private static final ImageFilter filter = new RGBImageFilter() {
    int transparentColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0).getRGB() | 0x0000ffcc;

    public final int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {
        if ((rgb | 0x0000ffcc) == transparentColor) {
            return 0x0000ffcc & rgb;
        } else {
            return rgb;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Not sure what the purpose of `g2d.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(transparentImg.getSource()), x, y, null);` is for, `transparentImg` is already an instance of `Image`

Comment: `utilGraphics.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, nw, nh, null);` seems odd, as you're painting the image, which is represented by `utilGraphics` back onto itself .... ?

Comment: 1. I used that for something else, forgot to delete it.

Comment: 2. I created a scale variable, that was multiplied by the previous width to allow it to become multiplied by a float. I can't really explain it well, but I hope you understood.

Comment: You don't understand - the `utilGraphics` is the `Graphics` context from `image1` (used to center the original image), you then paint itself to itself - you never create a new `Graphics` context for `image` (rotate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ...

```
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(nw, nh, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    centeredGraphics.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, nw, nh, null);
```

You're creating a new `BufferedImage` (`image`), but you never actually paint anything to it, instead, you paint `image1` to it's own `Graphics` context.

Now, if you wanted a transparent image, you should have used...

```
BufferedImage centeredImage = new BufferedImage(radius, radius, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

instead of...

```
BufferedImage centeredImage = new BufferedImage(radius, radius, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
```

And I never used `g2d.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(transparentImg.getSource()), x, y, null);` as it just doesn't make sense to me (`transparentImg` is already an `Image` ‍♂️)

Now, having said all that, I would "suggest" you take each step individually, start by scaling the original image using something like [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) and the rotate the image using something like [Rotate a buffered image in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758061/rotate-a-buffered-image-in-java/37758533#37758533) (which will generate a image large enough to contain the rotated image)

Also, if you "create" a `Graphics` context, you should also `dispose` of it when you no longer need it, otherwise you could end up with a memory leak.

## "Fixed" code...

Just to be clear, I would still recommend sing `ARGB` instead of `RGB` for `centeredImage` as your filter workflow never seemed to work for, but I started with a transparent image anyway

```
public Image rotateAndScaleImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int degrees, float scale) {
    // make rectangular image
    int radius = (int) Math.sqrt(originalImage.getWidth() * originalImage.getWidth() + originalImage.getHeight() * originalImage.getHeight());
    BufferedImage centeredImage = new BufferedImage(radius, radius, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D graphics = centeredImage.createGraphics();
    // centers image

    int xPos = (centeredImage.getWidth() - originalImage.getWidth()) / 2;
    int yPos = (centeredImage.getHeight() - originalImage.getHeight()) / 2;

    graphics.drawImage(originalImage, xPos, yPos, null);
    graphics.dispose();

    // scale image
    int nw = (int) (centeredImage.getWidth() * scale);
    int nh = (int) (centeredImage.getHeight() * scale);

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(nw, nh, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    graphics = image.createGraphics();
    // No scaling is done ???
    graphics.drawImage(centeredImage, 0, 0, nw, nh, null);

    // Rotation information
    double rotationRequired = Math.toRadians(degrees);
    double locationX = centeredImage.getWidth() / 2;
    double locationY = centeredImage.getHeight() / 2;

    AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(rotationRequired, locationX, locationY);
    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

    ImageProducer filteredImgProd = new FilteredImageSource(op.filter(centeredImage, null).getSource(), filter);
    Image transparentImg = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(filteredImgProd);

    return transparentImg;
}

private static final ImageFilter filter = new RGBImageFilter() {
    int transparentColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0).getRGB() | 0x0000ffcc;

    public final int filterRGB(int x, int y, int rgb) {
        if ((rgb | 0x0000ffcc) == transparentColor) {
            return 0x0000ffcc & rgb;
        } else {
            return rgb;
        }
    }
};
```

Oh, and I'm returning an `Image` because I painted directly to a component for testing

Comment: Did you test this over black? Because for me, I cannot get it to work. It can rotate, but it doesn't have a transparent background. Instead, the background is black. Is there something wrong on my side? Or is there some kind of solution? I am new to swing as a whole, so I'm having a hard time.

Comment: @BumholeStupid I tested this with a transparent PNG (using `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB`) and it generated a image with a black background - the "filter" didn't seem to work as you expect it - are you input images transparent? If they are, and as I stated, used `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` instead